# Accessing a variable outside of a closure

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm pretty confused by the JavaScript scoping. I have a call to `FB.api` (shown below) that I would like to return a response object:

```
(function() {
    var permissions;

    FB.api("/me/permissions", "get", {access_token: options.token}, function(r) {
        permissions = r;
    });

    console.log(permissions);
})();
```

Ideally, I'd like to assign FB.api to a variable, and use the anonymous function to return the `r` component, but it appears like that's not doable.

Why is `permissions` undefined? Is there a way to set permissions in the parent scope?

Comment: FYI, the problem is not scope, but timing. You are calling `console.log(permissions)` **before** `permissions = r;` is executed. This is probably one of the most asked questions here.

Comment: Ah, thanks Felix. I appreciate it. Is there a good resource for teaching users how to manage this? I'm not sure what I should be using for search terms. Many thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate questions. Searching for "asynchronous JavaScript" should also yield results. Solutions are "callbacks" and especially "promises".

Comment: Thanks Felix, you've helped tremendously.